# How to execute ImageMagick command from PHP's shell_exec?

Tags: php, macos, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, imagemagick-identify

```
$path = getenv("PATH");
putenv("MAGICK_HOME=/Users/oa/Documents/software/ImageMagick-7.0.7");
putenv("DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/oa/Documents/software/ImageMagick-7.0.7/lib");
putenv("PATH=/Users/oa/Documents/software/ImageMagick-7.0.7/bin:".$path);

$output = shell_exec("convert -page +0+0 src.jpeg foo.gif");
```

I get:

> dyld: Library not loaded:
>   /ImageMagick-7.0.7/lib/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.4.dylib   Referenced from: /Users/oa/Documents/software/ImageMagick-7.0.7/bin/convert
>   Reason: image not found

Comment: Try setting your `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` by *appending* to your existing, same as you already do for `PATH`.

Comment: Else try `var_dump($_ENV)` to see how it differs from your environment in the shell in Terminal where, I assume, the command works.

Comment: @MarkSetchell `var_dump($_ENV)` is an empty array...